# Iterator: pairing up last element with a different value

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a List[String] like the following:

```
val xs = List("apple", "orange", ..., "pear", "dragonfruit")
```

I would like to produce the following, resulting list:

```
List(("apple", ","), ("orange", ","), ..., ("pear", ","), ("dragonfruit", ";"))
```

Note that the last pair has a semicolumn rather than a comma.
Can I do this without knowing the length of the list? More generally, is there a functional version applying to Iterable?

```
def pairUp[A,B](xs: Iterable[A], nonlastB: B, lastB: B): Iterable[(A,B)]
```

Every x in xs except the last should get paired up with `nonlastB`, and the last one with `lastB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foldRight` for this.

In your example, you have

```
"apple" :: "orange" :: ... :: "pear" :: "dragonfruit" :: Nil
```

And you want

```
("apple", ",") :: ("orange", ",") :: ... :: ("pear", ",") :: ("dragonfruit", ";") :: Nil
```

The intuition for foldRight is that it does constructor replacement.

`l.foldRight` takes two parameters. The first one replaces the constructor `Nil`, the seconds replaces the constructor `::`, so you have `l.foldRight(nilReplacement)(consreplacement)` Now let's take a look at what replacements you want for `Nil` and for `::`:

```
"apple"        :: "orange"        :: ... :: "pear"        :: "dragonfruit" :: Nil
("apple", ",") :: ("orange", ",") :: ... :: ("pear", ",") :: ("dragonfruit", ";") :: Nil
```

- `Nil` stays `Nil`
- `x :: Nil` becomes `(x, ";") :: Nil`
- `x :: other` becomes `(x, ",") :: other`

so

```
val nilReplacement = Nil
val consReplacement = {
  case x :: Nil   => (x, ";") :: Nil
  case x :: other => (x, ",") :: other
}

xs.foldRight(nilReplacement)(consReplacement)
```

unfortunately, you'll find that `val consreplacement` fails to typecheck correctly because there is no expected type, and it infers the wrong type for `Nil` too soon. But giving it enough type hints fixes that problem:

```
xs.foldRight[(String, String)](Nil) {
  case x :: Nil   => (x, ";") :: Nil
  case x :: other => (x, ",") :: other
}
```

An entirely different approach goes straightforward through iteration:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

def pairUp[A,B](as: Iterable[A], nonlastB: B, lastB: B): Iterable[(A,B)] = {
  val it = as.iterator
  val builder = as.iterableFactory.newBuilder[(A, B)]
  def loop(prev: A): Unit = {
    if (it.hasNext) {
      builder.addOne(prev -> nonlastB)
      loop(it.next())
    } else builder.addOne(prev -> lastB)
  }
  if(it.hasNext) loop(it.next())
  builder.result()
}
```

You can use the somewhat complicated `Factory` infrastructure in the stdlib to abstract over input type:

```
def pairUpF[A,B, F[x] <: IterableOps[x, F, F[x]]](as: F[A], nonlastB: B, lastB: B): F[(A,B)] = {
  val it = as.iterator
  val builder = as.iterableFactory.newBuilder[(A, B)]
  def loop(prev: A): Unit = {
    if (it.hasNext) {
      builder.addOne(prev -> nonlastB)
      loop(it.next())
    } else builder.addOne(prev -> lastB)
  }
  if(it.hasNext) loop(it.next())
  builder.result()
}
```

Comment: This works nicely for Lists, but not for Iterables more generally, right?

Comment: For a generic iterable, you'll need to use the `+:` extractor instead of the `::` constructor, but you'll get back a `List`. If you want to get the same collection type back, you'll need to use a generic builder and go with iteration. That'll suck out all the prettyness, but it'll get the job done. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest 2 option, that might be less efficient than the other answers suggested here. But they are simple and short.

First, dropping the last element, and then add it later on:

```
xs.dropRight(1).map(l => (l, nonlastB)) ++ xs.lastOption.map(last => (last, lastB))
```

The second option I thought of is just is sliding on the `iterable`, and adding explicitly the last item with semicolon:

```
xs.sliding(2).map(l => (l.head, ",")).toList :+ (xs.last, ";")
```

Code runs can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/QChqB3DqTcSmVMb6a4tiWQ/17).